# Why i cant import txt files using numpy?

Tags: python

I am trying to import my data files to python using numpy. But it shows error message " data_file.txt is not defined " How to get rid of this ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50GFU.png)

Comment: Include the code you used. And the data_file.txt too.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to to put quotes around your variable name

Comment: An image is not the same a (indexable) text. Get rid of the image, cut and paste your code, then format it by using the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
fh = iter(open('data_file.txt'))
```

to get rid of the error. Or better use the filename that you defined:

```
fh = iter(open(filename))
```

BTW you don't need to put the assigned value in parenthesis:

```
filename = 'data_file'
```

is enough

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data_file.txt'

Comment: What part of "no such file or directory" don't you understand? If it doesn't exist, create the file first before trying to open it for reading.

Comment: But I have the file already. I think python cannot locate it. what should I do ?

Comment: Python can locate it perfectly fine, **you** are not providing the correct path. Always ask yourself: "What am I doing wrong?".  Don't you know what the current directory is ( `print(os.getcwd()`)? Which info you could use to provide a full path using `r"C:\path\to\your\data_file.txt"`. As you can't figure that out yourself, IMO you need other help (a mentor, basic programming instruction course) than posting on [so]

Comment: my current directory is C:\Users\vm Shareef Morayur\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.5.3.1Qt5\notebooks